# How to modify TeXstudio handling of some command (like \begin{flalign}) so I can use it as my own

Tags: macros, texstudio, editors

I am doing my undergraduate work in Electrical Engineering and I choose LaTeX as the tool for the job and TexStudio as my LaTeX editor. I had a pretty nice walk through LaTeX, but I begin to wonder what about some advanced stuff such as changing/modifying the handling of existing commands in the editor. My particular need is to make a `\begin{myflalign/myflalign*}` environment and configure the editor such that it would insert this code:

```
\begin{myflalign*}
    &  &
\end{myflalign*}
```

and position my cursor in between two `&` signs.

I do a lot of aligning and find that this command really suits me well and I only need a slight improvement of an existing command.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX. I don't understand your question. Do you want a new environment (myflalign), or do you want to configure your editor to automatically complete an environment and position the cursor? If you need a new environment, what do you want it to do?

Comment: This may be editor-specific, and not every editor can/will be able to do this. For a complete list of available editors, see [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://goo.gl/3f1mL).

Comment: Well I guess it is editor specific! And yes I want to configure editor to automatically complete and env and position the cursor... I use TexStudio, do you think this is doable?

Comment: @djudji Did you have a look at personal and [environment macros](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33)?

Comment: @djudji If my answer was helpful for you, I would kindly ask you to accept it by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) and would also raise your reputation. If there are any points left open, please add all necessary information to solve them.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a personal macro (see the [manual, Section 4.5](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33)). Since you would also like to position the cursor, it should be a script macro. Choose a name and a trigger (I chose `myenv` as the name and `%myenv` as the trigger). Whenever you type in the trigger, the trigger text will be removed and the script will be executed. The following script will do the trick:

```
%SCRIPT
cursor.insertText("\\begin{myflalign*}");
cursor.insertLine();
cursor.insertText("   &  & ");
cursor.insertLine();
cursor.insertText("\\end{myflalign*}");
cursor.movePosition(1, cursorEnums.PreviousLine);
cursor.movePosition(1, cursorEnums.StartOfLine);
cursor.movePosition(5, cursorEnums.Right);
```

It inserts the beginning of your environment, inserts a new line, inserts the `&` symbols, another new line, and the end of the environment. Then it positions the cursor by going one line upwards, then to the beginning of the current line, and finally 5 columns to the right to end up between the two `&` symbols.